# Wiring 3 wire well pump to 4 wire supply

Tags: electrical, well-pump

220v pump.

Old pump has 4 wires, RWBG
At the well head the supply has RWBground
Old pump use Green on ground.

New pump is black, black and green

Ok, 2 black supply lines go to Black and Red (Yes they have 240 between them)  But does my green connect to the neutral line (white) or to the bare ground wire.

Old pump is a 38 yr old franklin.

New pump is a Grundfos SQE series.

Comment: 3-wire well pumps almost never had "neutral" - they had a surface mounted capacitor and starting switch (and the usual color for the third wire was yellow, but that would depend on the wire/cable source.) Be sure to remove the surface mounted starting box from the circuit since you now have a two-wire pump.

Comment: The starting capacitor and starting switch at the wall was the typical 5 wire plug in cover.  I moved L1 and L2 to the appropriate wires outbound to the pump, bypassing the starter and capacitor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neutral is not needed here as the pump is 240V only with no N connection.  Connect the green to ground, and cap the white, and you should be all set.